# What data is POSTed to a shippo webhook?

Tags: symfony, shippo

I would like to implement a shippo webhook in order to know the delivery status of my shipments, their [documentation](https://goshippo.com/docs/webhooks) is a little unclear... I don't know what information will be passed to my script

I have setup a test URL and a live one and have added those to my account, in API -> Webhooks.

Whenever my script is requested either via the live or test URLs I get empty arrays, no data. Please help me figure this out. Anyone from Shippo??

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php

namespace MW\PublicBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class ShippoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/shippo/", name="shippo_web_hook")
     * @Method("GET|POST")
     */
    public function webHookAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
            $post = $request->request->all();
        } elseif ($request->getMethod() == 'GET'){
            $post = $request->query->all();
        }
        file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/shippo.txt', print_r($post,true));

        $mailer = $this->get('swiftmailer.mailer.transactional');
        $messageObject = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Shippo Webhook Posted DATA')
            ->setFrom('emai@example.com')
            ->setTo('email@example.com')
            ->setBody(print_r($post,true) . "\n" . print_r($_REQUEST,true) . "\n" . print_r($_POST,true));
        try {
            $mailer->send($messageObject);

        } catch (\Exception $e){

        }

        return new Response('OK');
    }


}
```

As you can see I should be able to catch some incoming data but I get nothing but empty arrays..

Comment: How is the response being handled? If you plug in a link from https://requestb.in/ you should be able to see what the response looks like when running a test webhook sample.

The only other time I've run into a similar situation with PHP was having to do with it trying to json_encode() on the response a second time.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed my script is receiving straight up JSON, thank you to mootrichard for sharing the requestb.in tool, with it I was able to see all the headers and data sent, just for future reference this is what I got.

```
namespace MW\PublicBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class ShippoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/shippo/", name="shippo_web_hook")
     * @Method("GET|POST")
     */
    public function webHookAction(Request $request)
    {
        $headers = $request->headers->all();
        $content = $request->getContent();
        if (!empty($content))
        {
            $post = json_decode($content, true);
        }
        if (isset($headers['x-shippo-event'][0]) && $headers['x-shippo-event'][0] == 'track_updated' &&
            (isset($headers['content-type'][0]) && $headers['content-type'][0] == 'application/json')){

            if (count($post) > 0) {
                file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/shippo.txt', print_r($headers, true) . "\n\n\n" . print_r($post, true));

            }


        }





        return new Response('OK');
    }


}
```

And the contents of shippo.txt is:

```
    Array
(
    [host] => Array
        (
            [0] => ******
        )

    [user-agent] => Array
        (
            [0] => python-requests/2.9.1
        )

    [content-length] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1021
        )

    [accept] => Array
        (
            [0] => */*
        )

    [accept-encoding] => Array
        (
            [0] => gzip, deflate
        )

    [content-type] => Array
        (
            [0] => application/json
        )

    [shippo-api-version] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2014-02-11
        )

    [x-forwarded-for] => Array
        (
            [0] => **.**.***.**
        )

    [x-original-host] => Array
        (
            [0] => *****
        )

    [x-shippo-event] => Array
        (
            [0] => track_updated
        )

    [x-php-ob-level] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

)



Array
(
    [messages] => Array
        (
        )

    [carrier] => usps
    [tracking_number] => 123
    [address_from] => Array
        (
            [city] => Las Vegas
            [state] => NV
            [zip] => 89101
            [country] => US
        )

    [address_to] => Array
        (
            [city] => Spotsylvania
            [state] => VA
            [zip] => 22551
            [country] => US
        )

    [eta] => 2017-09-05T01:35:10.231
    [original_eta] => 2017-09-05T01:35:10.231
    [servicelevel] => Array
        (
            [token] => usps_priority
            [name] => Priority Mail
        )

    [metadata] => Shippo test webhook
    [tracking_status] => Array
        (
            [status] => UNKNOWN
            [object_created] => 2017-08-31T01:35:10.240
            [status_date] => 2017-08-31T01:35:10.240
            [object_id] => ac0e0c060d6e43b295c460414ebc831f
            [location] => Array
                (
                    [city] => Las Vegas
                    [state] => NV
                    [zip] => 89101
                    [country] => US
                )

            [status_details] => testing
        )

    [tracking_history] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [status] => UNKNOWN
                    [object_created] => 2017-08-31T01:35:10.240
                    [status_date] => 2017-08-31T01:35:10.240
                    [object_id] => ac0e0c060d6e43b295c460414ebc831f
                    [location] => Array
                        (
                            [city] => Las Vegas
                            [state] => NV
                            [zip] => 89101
                            [country] => US
                        )

                    [status_details] => testing
                )

        )

    [transaction] =>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to their documentation they're just sending you a straight JSON response, not a key/value pair of data that you can get from the request parameters.  You would want to do something like this instead:

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
```

This documentation is from Silex but it's using the same components as Symfony to receive a [accept a JSON request body](https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/json_request_body.html#accepting-a-json-request-body).